# Angular Conditional Routing

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, socket.io

I am working on a somewhat simple chat app to familiarize myself with node/angular, but am typically a PHP developer. What I'm trying to do right now is make it so that if someone were to go to a room that does not exist, they would receive a page with a simple "Room does not exist" error message. But if it does exist, they would be able to join the room.

Right now, what I've been doing is using an `ngIf` in the view to display the error message if the server responds that it doesn't exist and to display the chat if it does exist.

I just don't quite care for how that works. Maybe it's just because of my normal background, but it feels weird to use the same view for multiple purposes based purely on what data returns.It seems very much like a less than elegant solution.

I'm using this as a one page app with ngRoute. Is there a way through Routes or some other method that I could do a check for the room before the route fires and redirect based on that?

Comment: Assuming you're using the `resolve` block in your route configs to find the room (via an API or similar), you could always have the resolve fail if the room doesn't exist and catch it in the [`$routeChangeError`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#$routeChangeError) event handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the run block of your app you can watch the `$routeChangeStart` event, which is fired whenever you begin to change routes.  It is a good time to process any logic you need to before the new route loads.

> $routeChangeStart: Broadcasted before a route change. At this point the
>   route services starts resolving all of the dependencies needed for the
>   route change to occur. Typically this involves fetching the view
>   template as well as any dependencies defined in resolve route
>   property. Once all of the dependencies are resolved
>   $routeChangeSuccess is fired.

You can call `event.preventDefault()` to have it abort the route change and allow you to run whatever logic you need to.  You can then conditionally route, depending on how your logic resolves, to wherever you need to.

You can do something like this:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (myRoom) { 
            $location.path('myRoom')
        } else {
            $location.path('noRoom');
        }
});
```

If I recall correctly, you may need to wrap your $location changes in a $timeout function to get them firing.

```
$timeout(function() {$location.path('myRoom')},0);
```

Note: You can access details about the route you are heading to in the `next` parameter of the `$routeChangeStart` event, so if you need to grab details about what room they are trying to navigate to, you can get it from there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I wasn't even aware of app.run(). I'll try something like this and see where that gets me.

Comment: Phil is correct also - you can put logic in the `resolve` of the route as well.

Comment: I also added a note to the end of my answer that may be important in what you are trying to do.

Comment: Just implemented something very similar to this and it works exactly like I was wanting to. Thanks a ton!